# 401 error when requesting ASP.NET CORE with JWT auth

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

In my ASP.NET CORE project I use JWT authentication. Here's code from Program.cs:

```
// For authentication
var _key = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"];
var _issuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"];
var _audience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"];
var _expirtyMinutes = builder.Configuration["Jwt:ExpiryMinutes"];


// Configuration for token
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
{
    x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddJwtBearer(x =>
{
    x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    x.SaveToken = true;
    x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidAudience = _audience,
        ValidIssuer = _issuer,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_key)),
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(_expirtyMinutes))

    };
});
```

In addition I want to allow requesting anonymous requests for some methods in one controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public class ScheduleController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Week()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

But I get error with 401 status when request such a method from client.

How can it be solved?

Version of dot net is `net6.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with authorization but with routing. I just had to determine template for this attribute:

```
[HttpGet("week")]
```

And now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

One easy to manage option is to configure authorization like this, which enables anonymous routes to work, and all others to require a JWT:

```cs
private void ConfigureAuthorization(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
    });
}
```

There are other possible configurations - [this post](https://andrewlock.net/setting-global-authorization-policies-using-the-defaultpolicy-and-the-fallbackpolicy-in-aspnet-core-3/#using-the-fallbackpolicy-to-authorize-everything) has some good notes on the fallback policy.